# Aplication has stopped unexpectedly. please try again android

Tags: android

im developing my project in android. The project is about calculating matrix. I did all the 2x2 and 3x3 matrix (sum, subtraction, multiplication and det) in the 4x4 i did the det but when i try to sum, sub or mult the program crashes.
PS: sorry my bad english.

Here's the Logcat:

```
06-09 16:32:50.658: D/dalvikvm(961): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 41K, 53% free 2543K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 93ms
06-09 16:34:22.848: D/dalvikvm(961): GREF has increased to 201
06-09 16:34:44.098: D/AndroidRuntime(961): Shutting down VM
06-09 16:34:44.098: W/dalvikvm(961): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.wololo.matrizes.tela4x4Activity$6.onClick(tela4x4Activity.java:410)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-09 16:34:44.108: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to learn from the stack trace. Those messages are very informative and `NullPointerException` is, in general, the easiest problem to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests that you've got a null object at

```
com.wololo.matrizes.tela4x4Activity$6.onClick(tela4x4Activity.java:410)
```

i.e. line 410 if your file tela4x4Activity.java.  So look at that line, work out which object is null, and fix.

Comment: My line 410: c42.setText(String.valueOf(cc42));

Comment: LOL, basic error. Fixed it thx